# Is there a python 3 file extension that acts exactly like a *.py extension?

Tags: python, file-extension

I am writing an open source project in python, and in order to make it easier for another developer to add to it, I would like to have all of my code to have another file extension, so that my installer/updater can tell the difference between my files and the other developers files (these would be unique to their computer). What the installer would do is delete all of my program files, then download the latest ones and put them in the directory. In order to make these files combine, at the end of my main program, I would add in a few lines of code to check if any of the conditions in the other developers files occur (I am making a digital assistant using the Chinese room thought experiment as a basis, so the main program is basically hundreds of `if`, `elif`, and `else` statements, pointing to modules telling the main program what to do).

Comment: *"the main program is basically hundreds of if, elif, and else statements"* That doesn't sound right. Sure you couldn't do it differently? Anyway, what about using git for version control, viewing differences, merging edits etc.?

Comment: I have the main program as, basically `if UserInput=="hello": print("Hi")` and other, more advanced if statements, because it is the easiest way to do this, as far as I know. And I haven't used git because I have had almost no experience with it, and I have already got an install file, and published it on my website (alaricwhitehead.wix.com/artist), so a change wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: It sounds like you're building a dictionary where one word/key, e.g. "hello" maps to another word, i.e. "Hi". Why not use a python dictionary and a single `if` instead? Your program could be a large json file or a database and 5 lines of python if that's all it does

Comment: The Chinese room thought experiment (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room) is basically a dictionary, and that is the model I have decided to work with. However, a dictionary may not be too suitable for what I want, because A: I haven't ever used one before, so have no idea how they work, B: I'm already hundreds of lines in, and C: the program doesnt just respond to statements/questions, it performs actions such as searching for files on the computer, and playing music files/creating playlists. Plus, python is the language I have used the most, so I would rather stick with it.

Comment: Yes yes, I've read John Searle - interesting stuff. I wasn't trying to be rude or anything; it just struck me that python has a datatype that's actually *called* a dictionary and that it's made for exactly this purpose. I'm not talking about changing the programming language. I can write a quick example of what I mean if you're interested. Regarding the file extension stuff; if you insist on not using git or some other version control system, you could add a custom file extension to your OS that gets opened by python. It's a hacky solution but it should work.

Comment: Sorry if I came across as being annoyed, I think I misunderstood your last post and so decided to clarify it for you. I said i would rather stick to python because i thought that .json files were specific to another language, so although I would be interested in learning about dictionarys, I would rather not have to change my program because it's already working well, and so I don't think there would be many benefits from changing it.  Adding another file extension may not be such a good idea for me though, as this is open source so it may not be the most efficient way of doing what I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107464/discussion-between-jdo-and-sonrad10).

Comment: Just to mention for any other novices, what OP's talking about here is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832) and jDo's advice all looks good (e.g. to tell your contributions from another dev's, use version control; avoid hundreds of if-statements, use dicts or some other way). That said, the main question and answer are still useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Is there a python 3 file extension that acts exactly like a *.py extension?"*

No, not that I know of. If you want to do "version control" by creating your own file extensions (?!), you can use the `imp` module like so:

**Python 3.4.3 interpreter output:**

```
>>> import imp
>>> my_module = imp.load_source("My custom module", "my_module.some_extension")
>>> my_module
<module 'My custom module' from 'my_module.some_extension'>
>>> dir(my_module)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'func']
>>> my_module.func()
my module says hi!
>>>
```

**my_module.some_extension:**

```
def func():
    print("my module says hi!")
```

Answer (score -2):

Per https://github.com/github-linguist/linguist/issues/3323#issuecomment-259973104:

> The 1895 `.py3` files on GitHub are distributed among 392 repositories by 366 users. I'd say that's adequate enough distribution to warrant being included as an extension [to github-linguist].

Consequently, we can reasonably consider `.py3` to be an unofficial but widespread file extension for `python3` files.

Comment: That does no good if the PYthon interpreter won't allow you to import them. The `.py3` extension is just saying "this is a script for Python 3", so if anything it would be misleading to use it, and derive no particular benefit.

Comment: Files with a .py3 extension can't be imported normally.

Comment: “Imported normally”, @wjandrea? Can't you just set the file association?

Comment: How does it not provide any benefit, @ShadowRanger? You might be under the impression that a shebang is enough, but that doesn't work on non-POSIX OSes.

Comment: @RokeJulianLockhart: 1) The shebang actually does work on Windows [thanks to the PEP 397 Python launcher](https://peps.python.org/pep-0397/). 2) Python 2 has been end of life for three years now, the era of scripts differentiating Py2 from Py3 is ending. 3) The extension is 100% useless for *modules*, because `.py3` isn't a legal module extension, so imports would require ugly workarounds. It's purely for scripts. 4) The OP is looking for a way to differentiate their modules from other installed modules. They're all for the same Python version, so `.py3` is not meaningful, even if it worked.